# Docker pm2 not running in other image

Tags: node.js, docker

I have 2 images node and nginx. But issue I am facing is I install pm2 on node globally but its not working in other image or i dont know why its showing pm2 not found or I try with pm2-runtime but not working anything.

```
FROM node:14.21.3 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm i yarn@1.16.0
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@13.3.7
RUN yarn install --ignore-engines
RUN npm install -g pm2

# Copy the entire project directory into the container
COPY . .

# Build both frontend and backend
RUN yarn build-docker

FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy built Angular app from the builder stage to the NGINX HTML directory
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/client /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy built Node.js backend
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist

# Expose port 80 for frontend and port 9000 for backend
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 9100

# Start both Angular frontend and Node.js backend using PM2
CMD ["pm2", "start", "/app/dist/index.js", "--", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: It looks like the Dockerfile you've shown just builds a front-end application, and doesn't obviously have a backend component.  In the second stage you copy the static files into the Nginx server, and that should be enough.  If you delete the `CMD` and use the setup from the `nginx` base image, does it work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
...

FROM nginx:alpine

# Install Node.js and PM2 in the nginx image
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
RUN npm install pm2 -g
...
```

You need to install `pm2` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you are installing the pm2 application in the builder stage.

you have to give the command:
RUN npm install -g pm2

in the second stage (after the FROM nginx:alpine line)

for my use case I used this dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.22.10 as build
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./*.* .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:ssr

FROM node:12.22.10

EXPOSE 4001
RUN npm i -g pm2@4.5.0
RUN mkdir -p /dist/browser
RUN mkdir -p /dist/server
COPY --from=build /app/dist/browser/. /dist/browser/.
COPY --from=build /app/dist/server/. /dist/server/.
COPY --from=build /app/dist/*.js /dist/.

RUN pm2 start /dist/server.js --name site-name -o /dev/null -e /dev/null -i 3 --max-memory-restart 600M
RUN pm2 save
ENTRYPOINT [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "/dist/server.js"]
```

Comment: But it will not run because there were no npm. and its giving error /bin/sh: npm: not found

Comment: why are you use nginx?

Comment: edited my answer with dockerfile